# sqlite3_bind_parameter_index returns 0?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

The count returns a count of the parameters and is good.  However the index is returning 0.
Any ideas?

```
sqlite3 *database;
sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt;
int ID;
const char *sql;

sql = "update User set Name = ? , Dev = ?,ActiveLevel = ? Where _id = ?";


if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
  NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

NSLog(@"count %d",sqlite3_bind_parameter_count(updateStmt));

NSLog(@"Index %d",sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(updateStmt,"ActiveLevel"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_parameter_index.html):

> `int sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(sqlite3_stmt*, const char *zName);`
>   Return the index of an SQL parameter given its name.

And for [parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam):

> *?*
>   A question mark that is not followed by a number creates a parameter with a number one greater than the largest parameter number already assigned.
>   ...
>   *:AAAA*
>   A colon followed by an identifier name holds a spot for a **named parameter** with the **name :AAAA**.

Emphasis mine in the second section.

Your SQL doesn't have any named parameters at all, you just have plain old placeholders. The parameter name is the name of the placeholder (`:AAAA`), not the name of the column in question; remember that you can use placeholders in places where no name could be automatically derived so you have to name them yourself.

If you want to use `ActiveLevel` as a named parameter, then your SQL should look like this:

```
update User set Name = ? , Dev = ?, ActiveLevel = :ActiveLevel Where _id = ?
```

And you'd probably want to replace the other placeholders (`?`) with named parameters for consistency.

Comment: Ahhh I thought it was looking for the field names.  Thank you!

Comment: > remember that you can use placeholders in places where no name could be automatically derived so you have to name them yourself

What do you mean by that?

Comment: Ok, I tried out and I couldn't bind like this to a *table name* (sqlite3_preparev2 fails), so I guess that is what you meant by it.

Comment: Also worth to point out, that although `:`, `$`, and `@` can all be used to denote a named parameter, the "intuitive call" as the OP asked is wrong `sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(updateStmt,"ActiveLevel")`, the **prefix becomes part of the name**, so: `sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(updateStmt,":ActiveLevel")` will work. [from manual](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_parameter_name.html) *In other words, the initial ":" or "$" or "@" or "?" is included as part of the name*
(Tested in pure C)